# Measure space with full support

Tags: measure-theory

When a measure space is said to be with full support, what does this mean? Wikipedia provides information for other types of support, but not this one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It means that the support is the entire space, or equivalently that there is no open subset with 0 measure.